# 3.5DB splitter loss in voltage?

Tags: amplifier

I am trying to figure out the loss from a cable splitter. I am assuming it is analyzing any other filter circuit. This should equals a loss by a factor of 1.5 or is there some special nomenclature for splitters?

Comment: What are you splitting?  How are you splitting it?

Comment: @Majenko - a "splitter" is a fairly common device, sold off the shelf in connectorized form for coaxial systems, both 50 ohm and the 75 ohm "cable" TV systems consumers are familiar with.

Comment: Ah...  To me a "cable splitter" is any item which splits a cable into two - be that a coaxial, power, audio, whatever.

Comment: Such as a backhoe?

Answer (score 2):

The power ratio is the square of the voltage "ratio".

The power ratio is 10^-.35 or .44 - ie, just under half the power to each output with the total output power less than the input due to some loss (and/or approximation in the 3.5 dB number)

Taking the square root for the voltage ratio halves the exponent,

ie 10^-.175 or .668 of the input voltage.  Comparatively, for a lossless ideal splitter, you would expect SQRT(.5) or .707 of the input voltage on each output port.

There's an assumption that all ports connect to systems of the intended characteristic impedance; if not, the numbers will be skewed.

Answer (score 2):

The total power out can't exceed the total power in.  At best, the splitter will route half the input power to each of the two outputs.  That means the each output will be 10 log10(1/2) = -3dB from the input.  Of course the splitter won't be 100% efficient.

It's not clear what you mean by the "factor of 1.5".  *What* has this factor of 1.5?  If you mean a additional power loss of 1.5 due to inefficiency, then the outputs will at 10 Log10(1/1.2) = -1.8dB in addition to the inherent -3dB from splitting in two, for a total of -4.8dB each output.